# HTTP Interceptor Not Calling in NgRX Data Configured module

Tags: angular-ngrx-data

Beginner in NgRx Data

I have implemented NgRx data in one of my Application module. Everything is working fine the only concern is api's that i am using in NgRx data configured module not triggering the HTTP Interceptor where i configured my Auth Token on Application level.

All other modules where NgRx is not configured is calling HTTP Interceptor properly & setting the TOKENS in API'S properly.

Is it Mandate to store token in NgRx Store then only API'S will call HTTP Interceptor?

Just an FYI.
I am not using NgRX store for Storing Token as of now i am storing in localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

From your question w/o any code snippet, it is difficult to understand  actual problem. If I understood it clearly you want to add token before request goes on wire. In this case you may want to implement `HttpInerceptor`. Refer below code snippet. You can check more on it from [Bezocder](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-security-postgresql-jwt-authentication/) This should solve your problem.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    let authReq = req;
    let jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    if (jwt != null) {
        // for Spring Boot back-end
        authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + jwt) });
    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
}
```